# Command-line software for playlist syncing to Android Phone?

Tags: command-line, music, android

I'm looking for a way to sync music to my Android Phone without having to load something like banshee. I know there are plenty of ways to sync *files*, but I'm interested in syncing *playlists* and having the playlists dictate which files are synced.

Comment: What do you consider a "playlist"?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming an m3u exported from banshee and you have your Android mounted you can do something like:

```
rsync -avu --files-from=yourlist.m3u  <MUSIC_DIR>  /media/ANDROID/<ANDROID_MUSIC_DIR>
```

For example:

```
rsync -avu --files-from=yourlist.m3u "/home/user/Music" "/media/ANDROID/MUSIC"
```

You can also add --delete

```
rsync -avu --delete --files-from=yourlist.m3u "/home/user/Music" "/media/ANDROID/MUSIC"
```

I tested with a simple m3u and worked, but it may need some tweaks for a complex one.

Comment: I do something somewhat similar, but I have QuickSSHD on my android so I sync through ssh and dont have to mount it (it also makes the process faster since the android can scan its files instead of having to go through a mount). The other difference is I have a list of which m3u files I want synced and basically merge them all together (and include the m3u files in the sync) for one big rsync. But this is definitely the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I can only assume you mean that you want certain files (playlists) to contain rules to move certain other files (music) to another location (your android).

Seeing as you don't want to start any applications, I would suggest using a simple text file that contains the names of songs in the playlist. Write as many of these as you want.

Then you could write a short script called `playlist_sync` that will read the lines in each playlist, search your music directory (using a [regex](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=regular%20expression&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression&ei=eoA6T6OFO6aZ0QHu66GsCw&usg=AFQjCNGjZ9Ib5o06o3PyyIuIlQ7E05b5pA)) for files that match your song names and copy them over to a certain device.